# Why are ufuncs 2x faster on one axis over the other?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-ufunc, numpy-ndarray

I measured performance of ufuncs like [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) over different axes:

```
In [51]: arr = np.arange(int(1E6)).reshape(int(1E3), -1)

In [52]: %timeit arr.cumsum(axis=1)
2.27 ms ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [53]: %timeit arr.cumsum(axis=0)
4.16 ms ± 10.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

[`cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) over axis 1 is almost 2x faster than over axis 0. What is going on behind the scenes?

Comment: The contrast is larger on my machine. I can imagine row-wise sums are more cache friendly.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Very well could be, because I was trying this on a cluster :). Also, it was not only `sum` almost all ufuncs which can be reduced over the axes behave the same way

Comment: @kmario23 Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a square array.  It looks like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

But computer memory is linearly addressed, so to the computer it looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Or, if you think about it, it might look like this:

```
1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9
```

If you are trying to sum `[1 2 3]` or `[4 5 6]` (one row), the first layout is faster.  If you are trying to sum `[1 4 7]` or `[2 5 8]`, the second layout is faster.

This happens because loading data from memory happens one "cache line" at a time, which is typically 64 bytes (8 values with NumPy's default dtype of 8-byte float).

You can control which layout NumPy uses when you construct an array, using the `order` parameter.

For more on this, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order

Answer (score 7):

The arrays are [row-major](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues). Therefore, when you're summing over axis 1,
the numbers are found in contiguous memory arrays. That allows for better cache performance and therefore faster memory access (cf. "[Locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)"). I assume that that's the effect you're seeing here.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the performance will depend on the order of the array in memory:

```
In [36]: arr = np.arange(int(1E6)).reshape(int(1E3), -1)

In [37]: arrf = np.asfortranarray(arr) # change order

In [38]: %timeit arr.cumsum(axis=1)
1.99 ms ± 32.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [39]: %timeit arr.cumsum(axis=0)
14.6 ms ± 229 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [41]: %timeit arrf.cumsum(axis=0)
1.96 ms ± 19.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [42]: %timeit arrf.cumsum(axis=1)
14.6 ms ± 148 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

For more details, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues